# ddr3 ram wipe/delete using command prompt Windows10

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, ramdisk

I would like to know how-to, or if it is in fact possible, to completely erase or clear my ram using command prompt.

Comment: Switch your computer off. RAM is volatile & doesn't survive a power-cycle.

Answer (score 0):

RAM or RAM-disk?

The RAM cannot be erased without killing the OS that is doing the erasing.

A RAM-disk can be cleared as any other disk via full format.

Otherwise, you might have meant 
[How to Make Windows Clear Your Page File at Shutdown](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/314834/how-to-clear-the-windows-paging-file-at-shutdown),
or was asking after products such as [CleanMem](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/cleanmem-a-memory-cleaner-that-works/) or [Minimem](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/reduce-your-pc-memory-usage-with-minimem/)
(which I do not recommend using).